# Animate RelativeLayout margin change

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-animation

Code:

```
RelativLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativLayout.LayoutParams) view1.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);
view1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The above code is working fine, but I want to animate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `ValueAnimator` like this:

```
ValueAnimator varl = ValueAnimator.ofInt(50);
varl.setDuration(4000);
varl.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view1.getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(), 0, 0, 0);
        view1.setLayoutParams(lp);      
    }
});
varl.start();
```

The `ValueAnimator` is available from Honeycomb but you have the `NineOldAndroids` port.

Comment: Use actionbar sherlock version - com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet, use Animation:

```
Animation animation = new Animation() {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LayoutParams params = view1.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = (int)(50 * interpolatedTime);
        view1.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
animation.setDuration(300);
animation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
view1.startAnimation(animation);
```

Or better still, use a helper [library](https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator):

```
ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(view1).leftMargin(50).setDuration(300).start();
```